# Off-line load in the balls-and-bins problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

In the balls-and-bins problem with $n$ balls thrown into $n$ bins, we seek to minimize the maximum load (i.e., number of balls in any bin). If each ball is given two choices, in the **off-line** setting where the choices of all balls are known, it has been shown (cf. Lemma 14 in [this paper](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~azar/box.pdf)) that with high probability, there is an assignment with maximum bin load $O(1)$.

My question is a variant of the above scenario. Now consider that the $n$ balls are colored, for the sake of concreteness, let's consider the case where there are $\sqrt{n}$ colors, each containing $\sqrt{n}$ balls. In my problem, the load of a bin is the number of colors of the balls thrown into it (compared to the number of balls in the standard version). Again, each ball randomly chooses $2$ bins. I want to know that how many bins are required (in order of magnitude) to ensure that with high probability, there is an assignment with maximum bin load $O(1)$ (i.e., containing $O(1)$ colors). Of course $O(n)$ bins are sufficient, but can we do better?